# Laravel RouteServiceProvider map function not called

Tags: php, laravel, caching, laravel-artisan

I'm using the `map` function in the `RouteServiceProvider` to manipulate some routes before are being processed any further.
When I run on my local machine everything runs fine but on the production server for some reason non of the map functions are being called.
To make sure the bug was not for some reason in my own code I used the orignal RouteServiceProvider.php with just some echo's added for testing purposes:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * This namespace is applied to your controller routes.
     *
     * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

    /**
     * The path to the "home" route for your application.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public const HOME = '/home';

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //

        echo 'RouteServiceProvider boot';
        parent::boot();
    }

    /**
     * Define the routes for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function map()
    {
        echo 'RouteServiceProvider map';
        $this->mapApiRoutes();

        $this->mapWebRoutes();

        //
    }

    /**
     * Define the "web" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes all receive session state, CSRF protection, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapWebRoutes()
    {
        echo 'RouteServiceProvider mapWebRoutes';
        Route::middleware('web')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    }

    /**
     * Define the "api" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes are typically stateless.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {
        echo 'RouteServiceProvider mapApiRoutes';
        Route::prefix('api')
            ->middleware('api')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    }
}
```

When running on production server I get:

```
RouteServiceProvider boot
```

When running on local machine:

```
RouteServiceProvider bootRouteServiceProvider mapRouteServiceProvider mapApiRoutesRouteServiceProvider mapWebRoutes
```

So it seems on the production server the class is perfectly loaded and the `boot` function also is called but the none of the `map` function are.
I've tried clearing every type of cache but the result remained the same. However during the cache clear it DOES call all the map functions:

```
php artisan route:cache
RouteServiceProvider bootRoute cache cleared!
RouteServiceProvider bootRouteServiceProvider mapRouteServiceProvider mapApiRoutesRouteServiceProvider mapWebRoutesRoutes cached successfully!
```

Any idea what might be causing this or how to resolve it?

PS On the production server everything is deployed using PHP Deployer, but everything else is running fine so I assume that's not the issue.

Comment: are php versions same on prod & your local mach?

Comment: @kresimir-pendic yes, both 7.4

Comment: What is the output of ```php artisan route:list``` on prod?

Comment: Did you clear and cache the routes again? Because if routes are loading from cache, the map functions should not be called I believe. ```php artisan route:clear``` and ```php artisan route:cache```

Comment: @KurtFriars a lot ;) it's showing all the routes specified in the web.php and api.php like it's supposed to

Comment: @ArnovanOordt Yes, I think it is a cache issue then

Comment: Since you are carrying out logic in your map() methods, please see my answer below to show how to disable the route cache, and why you need to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the frameworks default RouteServiceProvider, (Not the one that your application extends), You will see:

```
/**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->setRootControllerNamespace();

        if ($this->routesAreCached()) {
            $this->loadCachedRoutes();
        } else {
            $this->loadRoutes();

            $this->app->booted(function () {
                $this->app['router']->getRoutes()->refreshNameLookups();
                $this->app['router']->getRoutes()->refreshActionLookups();
            });
        }
    }
```

As you can see `if ($this->routesAreCached()) {` then the routes are loaded from cache, and `$this->loadRoutes();` is what ultimately calls the `map` function of your RouteServiceProvider.

If you do `php artisan route:clear` it will stop the routes from being loaded from cache, and your map methods will be called on each request.

Answer (score 3):

When you use route caching in production, `map` is not called anymore because its goal is to generate routes, and these routes are cached. If you check `Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider`, you will see:

```php
/**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->setRootControllerNamespace();

        if ($this->routesAreCached()) {
            $this->loadCachedRoutes();
        } else {
            $this->loadRoutes();

            $this->app->booted(function () {
                $this->app['router']->getRoutes()->refreshNameLookups();
                $this->app['router']->getRoutes()->refreshActionLookups();
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Load the application routes.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function loadRoutes()
    {
        if (method_exists($this, 'map')) {
            $this->app->call([$this, 'map']);
        }
    }
```